# Implementing a PDF renderer for HTML-formatted files in React

Tags: reactjs, pdf

Rendering external pdf.html format in react

Ihave a pdf file and this file has been converted to html file so i copied the all code and i need to render the same style in react component to print it after passing data to this component to give the user th pdf including the data he enetered however i faced thing s error 'warning: <%s /> is using incorrect casing. use pascalcase for react components, or lowercase for html elements.%s'

Comment: I'm sorry for my unclear question, but i will not be able to let tue user print the page that he use for the following reasons, this page is an input that i get data from then this data should be written in the the pdf when he ask for printing, for example this pdf is a contract including terms and conditions and some empty field like name of. Company.. Etc so when the use enter his data in the page that i have created and he press submit he will print a pdf contains terms and conditions including the entered data so to be able to control the pdf i converted it to html by converter website